# How to make this menu move with the page while being absolute

Tags: html, css, menu, position

The navbar that I am making is supposed to be touching the edges of the screen and so here is what I have so far.
css:

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height:65px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}
```

However I would like it to be able to stay with the page as you scroll down, unfortunately I can't figure out how to do it without changing the position from absolute; this doesnt work because it makes the menu bar not touch the edges of the screen.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What's the HTML, perhaps a http://jsfiddle.net/ may be of use to you here.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/VpRpt/

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;` and also give width to 100%.

**Edit**

You need to place your html of `<nav>` at bottom of the code and all other code would be better to wrap with a div here in your demo I have wrapped it with `<div class="main">`  and positioned it to relative and set top value.

[See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VATDf/1/)

Comment: WHen i do that the menu still does not move with the page as it scrolls, here is the code altogether by the way: http://jsfiddle.net/VATDf/

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have any HTML to work of off, I'm just taking a shot in the dark.

If the nav is inside of any other element that's positioned relatively, the child element with absolute position will be trapped inside. Try moving the HTML outside of any containing elements, if it is.

Also, you can't have an element positioned absolutely left AND absolutely right. The lowest property in the list will take precedence of the the previous. You just need one. If 100% width is what you were going for, just add "width:100%;".

Comment: Those don't seem to be the problem, here is the code by the way: http://jsfiddle.net/VATDf/